# The dot product of two perpendicular vectors is not zero

Tags: vectors, tangent-line

The radius vector for a helix is 
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=a\cos(t)\ \mathbf{i} + a \sin(t)\ \mathbf{j} +c\ t\ \mathbf{k}$$
and it's tangent vector is
$$\mathbf{r}'(t)=-a\sin(t)\ \mathbf{i} + a \cos(t)\ \mathbf{j} +c\ \mathbf{k}.$$
They should be perpendicular to each other hence their dot product should be zero. But their dot product is $c^2t$. So they are not perpendicular unless $t=0$. How can it be?

Comment: I think you may be thinking of circular motion, wherein the acceleration vector is always perpendicular to the velocity vector.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, circular  helix is circular in 2D so Shouldn't the tangent vector be perpendicular on the radius vector in this case?

Comment: Not quite. The tangent/velocity vector is perpendicular to the acceleration vector. Try differentiating the tangent vector and then take the dot product and try for yourself.

Comment: jack yes they will be perpendicular. but i am still not getting why the tangent vector will not be perpendicular on the radius vector. Can you please explain? thanks very much

Comment: Imagine the helix contained in the surface of a cylinder. The tangent vector is always also tangent to the cylinder surface. However, the $r(t)$ you have is not always perpendicular to that surface. Calling it the radius vector is misleading, it is really the position vector, pointing from the origin to any point on the helix.

Answer (score 5):

The velocity is everywhere perpendicular to the position if and only if
$$ r'(t) \cdot r(t) = 0 $$
$$ 2r'(t) \cdot r(t) = 0 \implies r'(t)\cdot r(t) + r(t) \cdot r'(t) = 0$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (r(t) \cdot r(t)) = 0 \implies ||r(t)||^2 = c$$ so the length of the position vector must be constant i.e. the motion is on a circle (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) or a sphere (in $\mathbb{R}^3$). The helix doesn't lie on a sphere, so it's not true that the velocity is perpendicular to the position. So if you had circular motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then yes it would be perpendicular, but your motion is in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: understood. thanks very much for the answer

Comment: You should note that both $r$ and $r'$ must not have zeroes.